# ¿Cómo solucionar el desbordamiento del footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

No logro encontrar que propiedad es la causante del desbordarmiento de la página que estoy creando con bootstrap, he estado investigando de como hacer para que el footer no haga el desbordamiento de la página, pero no doy con el problema, no se si realmente me falte una propiedad o es que haya movido una propiedad el cual me quite ese problema del desbordamiento que tengo con el footer. Investigando con la consola del navegador supe que era el footer el cual me arrojaba ese desbordamiento y por eso he estado buscando alguna solución pero no la encuentro. Espero que alguien pueda guiarme en este problemilla que tengo con la página y de antemano gracias.

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo a como usar bootstrap ya que css nativo no logro comprenderlo mucho y se me hace más fácil utilizar bootstrap

```css
#header img{
    width: 80px;
}

.text-contacto{
    color: #5fafce !important;
}

#main .carousel-inner img{
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: grayscale(70%);
}

#carousel{
    position: relative;
}

#carousel .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}

#carousel .overlay .container, #carousel .overlay .row{
    height: 100%;
}



#footer{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1c3643, #273b47 25%, #1e5372);
}

#footer a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer #copyrigth{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark" id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="./assets/img/electrodomestico.png" alt="Multiservicios Logo">
                    Multiservicios A & M
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#main">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
                        </li>
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-contacto" href="#">Contacto</a>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <!-- Main -->
    <main id="main">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-pause="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="./assets/img/pruena.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="imagen 1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./assets/img/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="imagne 2">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./assets/img/5.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="imagen 3">
                </div>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6 text-center text-md-end">
                                <h1>Multiservicios A&M</h1>
                                <p>Servicio especializado con más de 18 años de experiencia en la reparación de toda clase de electrodomésticos. Contactenos para agendar una visita a su domicilio y resolver los problemas de sus electrodomésticos. Te esperamos!.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light">Contactanos aquí!</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    
    <!-- Fotter -->
    <footer id="footer" class="pb-4 pt-4">
        <div class="contaier">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg">
                    <a href="#">Preguntas Frecuentes</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg">
                    <a href="#">Términos y condiciones</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <p id="copyrigth"> © Derechos reservados - Creado por Angel Monterverde Corrobarrutia</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como dice su [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#example) (traducido):

> Los carruseles no normalizan automáticamente las dimensiones de las
> diapositivas. Como tal, es posible que deba usar utilidades
> adicionales o estilos personalizados para dimensionar el contenido de
> manera adecuada.

En tu caso, sin las imagenes no hay tal "desbordamiento" (no se si yo lo llamaria así) de página. Por lo tanto son ellas con el carrusel que lo provocan. Aún así, no se si debería preocuparte demasiado, pues aunque fuerces una altura determinada, es probable que en otros dispositivos más pequeños u otras resoluciones pase lo mismo.

En todo caso aquí te dejo una posible solución, pero ya comento que lo que tu arregles ahora para tu dispositivo no es una solución universal para todos los demás, al menos esta que pongo a continuación no lo es.

```
.carousel .carousel-item {
  height: 300px;
}

.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

[Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28590046/10382744) a la fuente original del SO en inglés de este código.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda si funcionó, pero podrías explicarme un poco porque colocaste tales propiedades y tamaños? Aprecio tu ayuda bro.

Comment: Bueno, los tamaños eran de ejemplo, tampoco tenia claro si te iban a funcionar, piensa que si redimensionas la ventana quizas no te van a funcionar como esperas, o si lo abres en un movil o en distintos dispositivos, es cuestion de ir probando. Las clases son las que salen en el bootstrap 3, me extraña que te haya funcionado, deberian ser `carousel-item` ahora que lo veo. Lo encontré en alguna parte ayer del SO en inglés, ahora modifico mi respuesta con la clase correcta.

Comment: Acabo de agregar el enlace a la fuente original de ese código del SO en ingles al pie de mi respuesta.  Saludos!